# Microsoft Azure AD/ Microsoft Graph API AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to implement a feature in our web app which allows users to connect their `Microsoft/Outlook` accounts to see their calendar events and contacts from the `Microsoft Graph API` within our system.

I have this working just fine, except for a couple of things. It would seem as though the connected account life-cycle ends when the user closes their browser. This means that every time a user signs into our web app, if they view the calendar, they will be redirected to the Microsoft Login screen to sign in. This is not the normal way is it? I thought you were only redirected to sign in to authorize the web apps permissions one time?

My understanding was, once a user has granted permission for your app to connect to their account, unless they are 1) not currently signed in to the third party service or 2) have revoked your app permissions, then you will be able to access their data as per their allowances of permissions?

This is a very tedious implementation for something so simple, I am starting to think I have missed a critical piece of info along the way since I am currently going slightly crazy trying to create a nicer 'flow' within our web app.

FYI, I am using `adal.js` and `adal-angular.js` `1.0.9` from https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

**UPDATE 17/06/16**

I have moved away from the version o `adal.js` I was using and am now on the `experimental` branch which is working much more like expected. I still have some extra code to prevent an infinte iFrame loop, but there is a feature to prevent `adal` taking over back end requests which is very useful.

Comment: Are you storing the access token anywhere to use when the user returns?

Comment: No, I am confused as to how to re initialize the adal service with the id token, I hope I'm just missing something simple

Comment: @MartynC Just to add/clarify my previous comment, I could store the returned token, however, the code for parsing the token lives within a location change handler and there is no hook in to use a previously stored token. I also believe the token has an expiry, as there is a refresh token which can be sent by the library. Any attempt to parse an old token would fail, as the library stores a unique state value on the outgoing request, then validates on the incoming token. Essentially, I would need to rewrite the entire library it seems.

Comment: By default, adal.js uses HTML5 session storage to cache tokens.  Have you tried switching it to local storage?

Comment: @dstrockis I have enabled localStorage. I will update my answer when I get a chance with the latest info. I have a working solution at this stage, just took a lot of back and forth to get there